# What is the scope of "date_default_timezone_set()" function

Tags: php, timezone

I am using Laravel, and I have set the timezone `"UTC"` in the `config/app.php` file but I want to do the calculation in the `"America/New York"` timezone but if I use `date_default_timezone_set()` in any function then its scope will be for that particular function or it will be set for global scope

For e.g.

```
function xyz(){

date_default_timezone_set("America/New York");

}
```

If I set the `date_default_timezone_set("America/New York");` inside this function, it's scope inside this function or globally for the whole application, if it's scope for whole the application how to make this scope inside the function only

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I bet, it's globally. You can preserve the timezone value so it's the same as before after the function call like this:

```php
function xyz(){
    $tz = date_default_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set("America/New York");
    // do stuff
    date_default_timezone_set($tz); // reset timezone to old value
}
```

---

If you want, you can encapsulate that into an own function:

```php
function xyz(){
    temporary_timezone_transaction("America/New York", function() {
        // do stuff
    });
}

function temporary_timezone_transaction(string $temporaryTz, Callable $fn) {
    $globalTz = date_default_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set($temporaryTz);
    call_user_func($fn);
    date_default_timezone_set($globalTz); // reset timezone to old value
}
```

Comment: It is set globally for that request starting at that point.

Comment: I am little confuse because i have used date_default_timezone_set("America/New York") ;  in a function in our application, i found it's scope only on that function for e.g. i have used it  like this function xyz(){ date_default_timezone_set("America/New York") ;
//do stuff
}
after that i did not set in UTC i found it's scope is only in function xyz

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set("America/New York")` results in the timezone being UTC because PHP considers "America/New York" invalid. Turn on error_reporting and you'll see it.

Comment: i am writing like this date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');   not like this  date_default_timezone_set("America/New York") but i  found  in laravel it's scope at function level only why can any one explain